# Can I sign into my Pokemon Go account on a different phone with a different Google account?

Tags: pokemon-go

My friend decided to download Pokemon Go on my old phone which I had borrowed off another friend with her Gmail account and password. I got hooked playing it and reached level 16 but now I have to give the phone back to the original owner and I can't seem to log into the other account; it just started a new one on my Google account.

The account exists but how do I sign in to it? I have her email address and password or does it log onto the phone owners' Google account? How do I recover all the time and energy I've put into this? Starting again is not really an option.

Comment: Should have made a Trainer Club account, those are portable ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this through the PHONE SETTINGS :

AFTER CONNECTED TO A FACEBOOK ACCOUNT (nowadays it need to match the email /gmail your PoGo Acc is connected to)

```
  Go to  : 
 -> SETTINGS (your phone's "settings")
 -> GOOGLE SETTINGS
 -> (SOME phones have something between these two, i can only say it's called "Kontotjenester" in Norwegian) 
 -> CONNECTED APPS
 -> CHOOSE THE POKÉMON GO APP  (and confirm you want to disconnect it from Google)

--->>   NOW PROCEED THE PREVIOUS MENTIONED STEPS TO CONNECT IT TO A NEW GMAIL ACCOUNT:)
```

I do recommend you have it connected to some gmail even though you have it connected to Facebook as well - it's just safer. 
Good luck ♡

Answer (score 0):

The game saves progress data online, so usually when you log into an account that already has progress it has that progress on every device you have, as long as you are logged into the correct Account.

So since you played on her google account, that account has the progress saved, and as far as I know, there is no way to transfer data from one account to another. You'd either have to keep using her account, or message Niantics support team and hope for a good response (which seem highly unlikely, but I guess it's worth a try).

Answer (score 0):

If you are entrusted with using her gmail you can add it to your phone without throwing her off her own phone. I have 3 devices on one of my gmails and they all work fine with it, even with them all switched on at the same time. That's the only way to keep your progress. You can not transfer your data to another account.

Once you've added that gmail account to your device you can log into your Pokémon Go account again.

***The downside of this is the account security.*** 

You can read her emails and vice versa, if you both send and receive emails with that gmail account. This also applies for the Pokémon account. Since its her gmail account she could log into Pokémon Go as well and play your character.

Answer (score 0):

1. Connect your Facebook to the pokemon go account you wish to transfer.
2. Log out and log back in using "Facebook" Instead of google.
3. Go to settings and deselect the "google" option
4. Deselect the "google" option and connect it to the new desired google account.

And there ya go. Your all set. If you wish to disconnect the Facebook from the account simply log out and back in using your google account at which point you can deselect the link Facebook option.